# firefox libva (VDPAU backend) crash

Tags: nvidia, firefox, flash

I see this problem recurring over and over browsing the web. I updated firefox to version 39.0 (version seems not to count that much anyway) and now when I open (supposedly) pages with flash content, firefox crashes. I am using pepper flash, I have the "use hardware acceleration" option switched off, I have an NVidia graphics card. I also update pepper flash. Let me add that until this morning it was working OK.

```
libva info: VA-API version 0.35.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_35
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_i965.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
NOT SANDBOXED
[fresh 15782] not implemented: PPB_OpenGLES2VertexArrayObject;1.0
[fresh 15782] not implemented: PPB_OpenGLES2DrawBuffers(Dev);1.0
[fresh 15782] [PPB] {zilch} ppb_network_monitor_update_network_list
```

Above the code snippet of the error reported. I did a `locate i965_drv_video.so` it it's not in my system. In `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/` I have other *.so* files.

What should I do?

Comment: the problem is mysteriously gone...

Comment: the problem is back... I googled more but can't find a way to fix it... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvdpau/+bug/1300215

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have fixed my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libvdpau1 libvdpau-va-gl1
```

then put this in your `~/.bashrc` file

```
export VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl
```

you can test with:

```
sudo apt-get install vpdauinfo
vdpauinfo
```